# Buffer module not loading with bower

Tags: javascript, jquery, bower, browserify

I need to convert a string to a buffer in the browser. Currently to manipulate DOM, I am using `jquery`. I have tried `bower install buffer --save` that pulls [this link](https://github.com/anodynos/node2web_buffer).

In my javascript code I type

```
const Buffer = require('buffer');
const bitcore = require('bitcore-lib')
const Mnemonic = require('bitcore-mnemonic');

let wordList = generateWords()
let wordBuffer = new Buffer(wordList);
let hash = bitcore.crypto.Hash.sha256(wordBuffer);
let bn = bitcore.crypto.BN.fromBuffer(hash);
let privateKey = new bitcore.PrivateKey(bn)
let publicKey = privateKey.toAddress();
console.log('private key ' + privateKey.toString());
console.log('publicKey ' + publicKey.toString());
console.log(wordBuffer);
```

This should output a buffer based on the input strings. However I get an error

```
bitcore-lib.js:1 Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'buffer'
    at s (bitcore-lib.js:1)
    at s (bitcore-mnemonic.js:1)
    at s (bitcore-mnemonic.js:1)
    at generate-address.js:3
    at generate-address.js:42
```

My html code loads the javascript files as follows

```
  <script src="../bower_components/bitcore-lib/bitcore-lib.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="../bower_components/bitcore-mnemonic/bitcore-mnemonic.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="../bower_components/buffer/buffer.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="../assets/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="../scripts/generate-address.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I am using `bitcore-lib` and `bitcore-mnemonic` as well in bower. I understand if people feel this is a duplicate question, however I have gone through over 10 questions and tried all the solutions but not able to fix this issue, so I am missing something out. Please help out. TIA

Answer (score 1):

You do not have to use the `require` method.

Try this:

```
let wordBuffer = new buffer.Buffer(wordList,'hex');
```